# django noob question regarding designing urls

Tags: django, url

I have a question on creating my url. I have a model like this -

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    subject = models.TextField()
    started_by = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='creator')
    target = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='receiver')

class UnreadItems(models.Model):
    unread = models.BooleanField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type','object_id')
```

I require a view whereby i return all unread conversations of the current logged-in user (i have around 3 classes of users in my application). For my url, I can probably have  `foo.com/conversation/unread?user_id=234fsg88j` or I can have simply use `foo.com/conversation/unread/` and use `request.user` to filter the user's conversation.

Is the latter a sounder approach and/or what is the disadvantage in using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admittedly, this is a pretty subjective question, But I tend to put data pertaining to a particular User at the front of the url.  Since conversations are a resource belonging to the user, that would follow the user.  Unread is really a predicate that filters out some of the data, much like a page range, or "starred" items, so that would end up in a query parameter.  Finally, I like my parameters to be easy to construct in javascript, so My url for this would look like

```
/users/tokenmacguy/conversations?unread=true
```

If the conversations should *never* be visible except to the user that owns them, then it would go on a resource that is per-user, something like

```
/my-profile/conversations?unread=true
```

Comment: I'm a `+1` for the unread being a parameter because later you could use other things like `unread=false` or `latest=10` or `top=50` etc. etc.

Comment: This way he will have to test if tokenmacguy == request.user.username, which seems a bit redundant IMHO. The unread filter as a parameter indeed makes sense.

Comment: @Paulo: The first way would show tokenmacguy's posts to *anyone* who is permitted to see them.  If that doesn't make sense in the context of the application, then the second suggestion is probably better.

Comment: Since the OP talked about 'current logged-in user', I understood it as a particular case, but in general lines you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

The latter is a sounder approach since it will make it much harder for people to see other users' unread conversations.

Answer (score 2):

Get the user from the request object unless unread conversations should be seen by anyone but the logged-in user.